# Material Table refreshes instead of appending onRowAdd

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have used the material-table from Material UI for React. When the data is passed statically, it displays row by row but when I bring data from a web service, already added row updates instead of appending a new row. Please help.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
columns: [
  { title: 'S.No', field: 'Id', type: 'numeric', editable: 'never' },
  { title: 'Roll Number', field: 'Studentid' },
  { title: 'Name', field: 'Name', editable: 'never' },
  { title: 'Year', field: 'Year', editable: 'never' },
  { title: 'Department', field: 'DeptName', editable: 'never'},
],
data: eventRegistrationStudentsList,
});

  <MaterialTable
    style={{ maxWidth: "95%" }}
    title="Student Details"
    id="studentDetailsTable"
    columns={state.columns}
    data={eventRegistrationStudentsList}
    editable={{
      onRowAdd: newData =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
              const data = [...state.data];
              data.push(newData);
              setState({ ...state, data });
              handleStudentIdChange(newData.Studentid);
              resolve();
        }),
      onRowDelete: oldData =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
            const data = [...state.data];
            data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
            setState({ ...state, data });
          }, 600);
        }),
    }}
    options={{
      search: false,
      actionsColumnIndex: -1
    }}
  />
```

eventRegistrationStudentsList holds:

```
[ DeptName: "AERONAUTICAL ENGINEERING",
Id: 1,
Name: "Jon",
Studentid: "190AE101",
Year: "III" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
data={eventRegistrationStudentsList}
```

You are updating the list in the state, but not using the list from the state

```
data={state.data}
```

here.

Comment: If I give data={state.data}, nothing is displayed on the table but row keeps adding.

Comment: How is that possible? It has to atleast show up for the initial load as `state.data` is `eventRegistrationStudentsList`

Comment: dunno why but I managed to make it work using `data={[...state.data]}`